# Why there isn't any exact formula to calculate summation of n terms of a HP?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, harmonic-numbers

When I search over the net to find such a formula all I find is the approximations but not exact. So, is it even possible to find the exact formula or is it the case that we will never be able to find an exact formula for this?

Comment: The problem in showing claims like "there is no exact closed formula" is that you first of all need to define what a closed formula is.

Comment: So, what is meant by a closed formula? Can't we define it by some common standard acceptable by all?

Comment: Nobody knows a formula that's simpler than the definition, I believe.

Comment: There is a formula which cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. $$\sum_{k=m}^n \frac 1 {a+kd}=\frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{a}{d}+n+1\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{a}{d}+m\right)}{d}$$ where appears the digamma function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you share some link where I can refer to this formula? I've tried to search online but didn't found any.

Comment: I made it for you. I do not know where you could get it. I shall work on it tomorrow morning and I shall post an answer. Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think I got yours covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only form (other than the original) that doesn't use special functions:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{r^k}k=\int_0^r\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}dx$$

You are mainly interested in $r=1$.

---

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\gamma+\psi^{(0)}(n)$$

where $\gamma:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\int_1^n\frac1xdx$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\psi^{(0)}(n):=\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\Gamma(n)\right)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Also note that...

$$\sum_{k=a}^b\frac1{dk+c}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{b+\frac cd}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^{a+\frac cd-1}\frac1k}d$$

and then use the above.

---

If you are interested in $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^p}$, it can be written as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^p}=\zeta(p)-\frac{\psi^{(p-1)}(n+1)}{(-1)^p(p-1)!}\tag{$p\in\mathbb N$}$$

where $\psi^{(p)}(n)$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) and $\zeta(p)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

---

If you allow the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) $\zeta(p,n)$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^p}=\zeta(p)-\zeta(p,n-1)$$

Comment: Good job, for sure +1